# How do I determine the generic type of an implemented interface using reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am writing something that needs to discover the types of all the properties in an object at runtime, using reflection. I'm fine with simple properties, I just get the `PropertyInfo` and the type is directly available. I can't work out what to do for generic collections, though. For example, suppose I am handed an instance of the following class at runtime:

```
public class AnyClass
  {
  public ICollection<int> ListOfInts;
  }
```

So I use `Type.GetProperties` and pretty soon I have my `PropertyInfo` object for `ListOfInts`.

What's my next step? How do I go from having the PropertyInfo, to working out that it is a list of ints? How can I determine the generic type (`<int>` in this example case) of the collection from just the `PropertyInfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for generic arguments of the type. See [PropertyInfo.PropertyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Type.GenericTypeArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`PropertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArgument`

Comment: Thanks - I must have been really tired yesterday because I looked for ages and couldn't find that option :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of the generic argument type:

```
propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name
```